# Focus on a TextBox in a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus, datatemplate

I have `DataTemplate` containing a `TextBox`. I'm setting this template to a listbox item on a selection.

I'm unable to set focus to textbox in the template. I tried to call MyTemplate.FindName, but it ends up with an Invalid Operation Exception: This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied.

How can I access it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you know the name of the `TextBox` you want to focus, this becomes relatively easy. The idea is to get hold of the template as it's applied to the `ListBoxItem` itself.

First thing you want to do is get the selected item:

```
var item = listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox1.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
```

Then you can pass that into this little helper function which focuses a control based on its name:

```
public void FocusItem(ListBoxItem item, string name)
{
    if (!item.IsLoaded)
    {
        // wait for the item to load so we can find the control to focus
        RoutedEventHandler onload = null;
        onload = delegate
        {
            item.Loaded -= onload;
            FocusItem(item, name);
        };
        item.Loaded += onload;
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        var myTemplate = FindResource("MyTemplateKey") as FrameworkTemplate; // or however you get your template right now

        var ctl = myTemplate.FindName(name, item) as FrameworkElement;
        ctl.Focus();
    }
    catch
    {
        // focus something else if the template/item wasn't found?
    }
}
```

I guess the tricky bit is making sure you wait for the item to load. I had to add that code because I was calling this from the `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` event and sometimes the `ListBoxItem` hadn't been fully initialized by the time we entered the method.

Comment: FindResource returns an object, so be sure to cast it to a FrameworkTemplate.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but I ran across this issue today and in the end came up with this resolution:

Since the `TextBox` is only being loaded when an item is selected, and that is when you want focus to be set, you can simply handle the `TextBox.Load` event and call `Focus()`.

There are two ways to achieve this.

**1. Replace the `TextBox` in the `DataTemplate` with an `AutoFocusTextBox`.**

```
public class AutoFocusTextBox : TextBox
{
    public AutoFocusTextBox()
    {
        Loaded += delegate { Focus(); }; 
    }
}
```

Don't forget you'll need to reference the namespace in which AutoFocusTextBox is defined in your .xaml file.

**2. Add a handler in the codebehind of the file where the `DataTemplate` is defined.**

*SomeResourceDictionary.xaml*

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Something, Mode=TwoWay}" Style={StaticResource ...
        Loaded="FocusTextBoxOnLoad" />
```

*SomeResourceDictionary.xaml.cs*

```
    private void FocusTextBoxOnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = sender as TextBox;
        if(textbox == null) return;
        textbox.Focus();
    }
```

With either option, you can always add other behaviour in the handler, such as selecting all text.

Answer (score 8):

Ok.  So I think I have the best solution.  It worked for me anyways.  I have a simple data template where I want to give focus to the text box.  The `FocusManager` hands off focus to the text box.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" DataType="ListBoxItem">
    <Grid>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tbText}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Completed}" Margin="5" />
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DeleteButtonTemplate}" Margin="5" Click="btnDeleteItem_Click" />
            <TextBox Name="tbText" 
                     Text="{Binding Path=Text}" 
                     Width="200" 
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                     AcceptsReturn="True" 
                     Margin="5" 
                     Focusable="True"/>
            <DatePicker Text="{Binding Path=Date}" Margin="5"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Jay's 2nd suggestion is neat - and can be more generalised by using `UIElement` rather than `TextBox`, so that any control can easily be made the default:

```
private void FocusControlOnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var uiElement = sender as UiElement;
    if(uiElement == null) return;
    uiElement.Focus();
}
```