# Set Focus to a textbox under a List DataTemplate

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm kind of new to WPF and XAML. I made a `Listbox` with textbox items and I wanted the textbox of the selected item to get focused whenever that item is selected. My friend suggested me to use `ItemContainer`, and I tried to use a trigger with a setter property of `TextBox.IsFocused`, but I kept getting an `IsFocused` cannot be set error.

What went wrong? Below is my code:

Updated the XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
            <Grid Margin="3">
                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black"
                          Background="{Binding RelativeSource=
                          {
                             RelativeSource 
                             Mode=FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}
                          }, 
                          Path=Background
                         }" CornerRadius="4">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" >
                        <StackPanel.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Style>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=BenefitDesc}"></TextBlock>
                        <Grid Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="White" Margin="3" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap">Price:</TextBlock>
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtUpdate" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Price}" Margin="3">
                            </TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="lsItem" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF2CB7D2" SelectionChanged="lsBenPriceEditor_SelectionChanged"
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="DarkRed" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329556/focus-on-a-textbox-in-a-datatemplate helps.

Comment: @MattHamilton I'm trying the first answer on that page and kept encountering the error method does not exists on the given line:var myTemplate = FindResource("MyTemplateKey"); I changed the var to Framework element, but this time I get an error object reference not set to a reference of an object

Comment: as per the comment on that answer, make sure you cast the return value from FindResource as a DataTemplate. FindResource just returns a System.Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook the SelectionChanged event in your code behind for your Listbox and there you can loop through the visual child of your SelectedItem to find your textBox and simply call `textBox.Focus()` to put the focus on the textbox.

**Code**

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
   ListBoxItem lbi = (ListBoxItem)lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(lb.SelectedItem);
   TextBox textBox = GetVisualChild<TextBox>(lbi);
   if (textBox != null)
      textBox.Focus();
}

private T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
{
   T child = default(T);
   int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
   for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
   {
      Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
      child = v as T;
      if (child == null)
      {
         child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
      }
      if (child != null)
      {
         break;
      }
   }
   return child;
}
```

GetVisualChild is generic method which you can use to loop through the VisualChildren for the passed `UIControl(ListBoxItem in your case)` and return the desired element `T(TextBox in your case)` from it VisualChildren list.

Moreover, IsFocused property exposed by UIElement is a get only property.

```
public bool IsFocused { get; }
```

That's why you are getting this error..

Comment: Very useful! Thanks for this answer.